# /locations/search API returning 500

Tags: instagram

I've been trying to search for location like this:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?access_token=<valid access token>&lat=34.052235&lng=-118.24368&distance=5000
```

and mostly getting return code 500. Occasionally (1 out of 10 or so) it does work, so I'm pretty sure the request is correctly formed.

The lat/long in the example are for Los Angeles, CA, but I see similar results with other lat/long's as well

Comment: interesting, I changed the lng=-188 and it worked, something specific to that value of lat/lng, not sure whats going on...

Comment: Does it work consistently with that change? When I was playing with it, it was just intermittent.

Comment: ya, worked consistently, what are u trying to do with this api? the data from this api returns many duplicate locations

Comment: I was adding a feature to Rokagram to find locations near the lat/long detected from the IP address of the user (the user's Roku box). When the API call returned non-500 (occasionally) I didn't notice duplicate locations, but it might be possible that I would miss them based on the way I process the return.

Comment: Playing with it a bit more and it does seem to work better if the decimal part of the lat/lng params is truncated down to an integer, but this won't really cut it because there's over 100 km between lines of latitude for example, and the search radius is only allows up to 5 km. Not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed getting 500 error in densely populated cities (such as NYC). To get around it, I had to shrink the search radius.

My guess is that there are simply too many locations in the region defined by the lat/lng and search radius.